# MacBook Pro Parallels (Kali) Linux Limited Screen Resolution

Tags: debian, kali-linux, virtual-machine, resolution, parallels

I installed Kali Linux 2.0 in a virtual machine running Parallels on my 15-inch MacBook Pro with Retina display.

For some reason the max resolution is 1920x1200. I have Parallels graphics set to 'More space' for the retina display.

I want to set the resolution higher to make it full screen and have nothing stretched out. How can this be done? It's running inside a window now and that looks fine, but I want to use the full screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you would need to have Parallels Tools installed to be able to use dynamic resolution.

Check these for possible ways to do that:

- http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22570.htm
- http://kb.parallels.com/113394

Comment: Is "Parallels Tools" something different from the "Parallels" that the OP says they have installed already?